# jQuery function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

I have a function which I copy from internet. It is working properly on load but when I add elements using prepend() spans on which function was already working start to blink I have add this to jsfiddle Please have a look any help will be appreciated.

```
$('.b').click(function(){
     $('.top').prepend('<div class="inner">brown fox jumps <span class="sinc"> 1462883724000 </span> </div>');
     $('.sinc').UpdateSince(1000);

});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {

  var times = this.map(function() {
    return {
      e: $(this),
      t: parseInt($(this).html())
    };
  });

  var format = function(t) {
    if (t > 86400) {
      return Math.floor(t / 86400) + ' days ago';
    } else if (t > 3600) {
      return Math.floor(t / 3600) + ' hours ago';
    } else if (t > 60) {
      return Math.floor(t / 60) + ' minutes ago';
    } else {
      return t + ' seconds ago';
    }
  }

  var update = function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    $.each(times, function(i, o) {
      o.e.html(format(Math.round((now - o.t) / 1000)));
    });
  };

  window.setInterval(update, interval);
  update();

  return this;
}
$('.sinc').UpdateSince(1000);

$('.b').click(function() {
  $('.top').prepend('<div class="inner">brown fox jumps <span class="sinc"> 1462883724000 </span> </div>');
  $('.sinc').UpdateSince(1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="inner">
    brown fox jumps
    <span class="sinc">1462883724000</span>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" class="b" value="click me">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're starting a new interval every time you click the button. You can either [clear the previous interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) before starting a new one or start the interval once and update the list.

Here's an example of clearing the interval:

```
var updateInterval; // Store the interval ID here

$.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {

  ...

  // Clear the previous interval
  clearInterval(updateInterval);
  updateInterval = setInterval(update, interval);
  update();

  return this;
};
```

Comment: Why? You literally just add two lines to your code.

Comment: It resolve blinking problem but it makes previous days to 16958 days ago which is not true. All have same micro time value 1462883724000 so result should be same

Comment: @Auj That's because you're using `$(this).html()` to get the interval time. So every timer after the first one uses `27` instead of `1462883724000`.

Comment: @Auj You could store that info in a data attribute like `data-start-time="1462883724000"` then access it using `$(this).attr('data-start-time')` instead of using `$(this).html()`.

Comment: Yeah thanks I already fixed it and if you just add data-id attribute and assign value to it. It fixes everything without any edit to original function. So just adding data-id or attribute you described will work nothing else needed. Cheers.

Comment: @Auj Great! Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

It is blinking because of the 1000 ms (1ms) time interval.TRy changing it to 30000 to see the difference.

```
        $('.sinc').UpdateSince(30000);
```

Comment: it is added to 1000 ms so it like this
1 sec ago
2 sec ago
3 sec ago upto 59 sec ago

then minutes, hours and then days.

Comment: Did you try changing for window.setTimeinterval(update,30000).. interveral codepen URL -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLjbvb

Comment: It resolve blinking problem but it makes previous days to 16958 days ago which is not true. All have same micro time value 1462883724000 so result should be same

Comment: Could you please share the expected result for each click i.e fist click 27 days ago , second click - 1462883724000 days ago??

Comment: Try using this.html() outside times function and assign it to variable and try it ..              $.fn.UpdateSince = function(interval) {
              x = $(this).html();
                var times = this.map(function() {
                  return {
                    e: $(this),
                    t: x
                  };
                });  
same codepen url -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLjbvb for reference